# How to filter records on a string date column using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL server database table that has a DueDate column. Data type of this column is nvarchar(50) and thus it saves dates values as string into this column.

I am using entity framework to get records from this table. My requirement is to get only those records whose DueDate is elapsed i.e records where DueDate <= TodaysDate. But as Linq to Entities does not support Covert.ToString() or Covert.ToDateTime() methods therefore I cannot compare the DueDate values with today's date value.

Kindly help me in fixing this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the database to store the dates as dates, your life will be much simpler in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your string to a date type, just like below:
I store the current date in a string (suppose it's like you read the date as a string from the database) and then I parse it to a datetime object.

```
string StringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(StringDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Ateeq. But your solution didn't work. I received following error message when I tried the solution you have mentioned.

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
string dateToCompare = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
var result = from Table in context.Table where Table.DueDate.CompareTo(dateToCompare) <= 0 
        select Table.ID;
List<int> resultBrands = result.ToList(); // it should be select just Table but I will show the results to be clear.
```

Here is results, (I use a test db)

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply Berkay. The solution you have provided will return only those records whose DueDate is today. But I also get those records which have DueDate lesser than today. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @MohitThakur it returns lesser than todays. Check 4th id. And DueDate at sql record.